# Map Over Array of Nested Objects in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an array objects that contain other objects. See below:

[JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnuaW.png)

I'm specifically trying to access the `name` and `url` properties inside the "buy_links" array.

Here's my code so far. `bestseller` returns data that I've mapped over elsewhere in my code - the trouble is just accessing that `buy_links` array. Currently my code doesn't break anything, but also doesn't return any data.

```
 <ul>
          {bestseller.buy_links.table.map(({ name, url }) => (
            <li key={url}>
              <a style={{color: "white"}} href={url}>{name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

Comment: `buy_links` is array

Answer (score 0):

You can not get it because `buy_links` is an array and you are accessing it as an `object`, so you need to do it like that.

```
<ul>
  {bestseller.buy_links.map(({ table }) =>
    table.map(({ name, url }) => (
      <li key={url}>
        <a style={{ color: 'white' }} href={url}>
          {name}
        </a>
      </li>
    ))
  )}
</ul>;
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to map over buy_links to access the `table` object. However React is now throwing a "table.map is not a function" error, I think the issue is that table is an object, and we can only .map over arrays? Should I iterate through the `table` object instead?

Comment: Yes we can only map over an array, for an object you need to convert it into an array using `Object.entries` and then you can iterate with map

Comment: Sorry to ask but could you add that into your code block so I can see how to implement properly? I've read up on the syntax and tried adding it to the table.map line by writing `Object.entries(table).map(({ name, url })` but it doesn't produce the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the `buy_links` as it is an array and then you can destruct all its properties like this:

First convert the JSON data to a JS object:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(YOURJSONDATA);
```

Then use map to display the object:

```
<ul>
  {bestseller.buy_links.map(({ name, url }) => (
    <li key={url}>
      <a style={{ color: 'white' }} href={url}>
        {name}
      </a>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>;
```

Comment: Thanks! When I run that code, the component is receiving the data (an array called buy_links with 5 objects inside of it) but it's not actually displaying the values. Strangely, five bullet points for the list items appear, but they're all blank.

Comment: Did you convert the JSON data to an object using json.parse()?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this working solution:

```
const copy = bestseller.buy_links.map(el =>
  <a href={el.table.url}>{el.table.name}</a>)
```